# Compiler warning for printf with Char ** (As an array of strings)

Tags: c

(Code condensed to relavent parts)

```
const char* cityCodes[nCities][3];

printf("%s", cityCodes[i - 1]);

TSP.c:40:16: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘const char **’ [-Wformat=]
```

So `cityCodes` is a `char **` (an array of strings). I get this warning by indexing said array to receive a specfic string. Is this compiler warning just something I should ignore? Is there any way around it?

Comment: `printf("%s", *cityCodes[i-1]);`

Comment: `const char* cityCodes[nCities][3]` is `const char***`.

Comment: Out of curiosity why is this const char***, but argv, which is also an array of strings, is only argv** ? What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

`cityCodes` is a 2-dimensional array of strings, so it's `char ***`.

I think you meant for it to be an array of strings that are each 2 characters (plus 1 byte for the null terminator). So the declaration should be:

```
char cityCodes[nCities][3];
```

If you want an array of pointers to strings, it should be:

```
const char *cityCodes[nCities];
```

When declaring a pointer, you don't specify the length of the array it points to.

Comment: Thanks! In the case of the latter example, by the way, the strings would have to be pre-existing at other memory locations, am I correct?

Comment: Or you can initialize it like `const char *cityCodes[] = {"XX", "YY", "ZZ", ...};`

Comment: You can also use that initialization with `char cityCodes[][3] = {"XX", "YY", "ZZ", ...};`